# Valgrind doesn't display any info (because of exec calls ?)

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, valgrind

I'm using valgrind to check memory leaks on a school project. the problem is valgrind only displays the first few usual lines of presentation but doesn't give me any info on leaks and errors :

```
==4734== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4734== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4734== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4734== Command: ./pipex test_infile grep\ test wc\ -l test_outfile
==4734==
```

When I run the program without any arguments, it shows info correctly :

```
==4626== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4626== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4626== Using Valgrind-3.16.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4626== Command: ./pipex
==4626== 
ERROR
==4626== 
==4626== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4626==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4626==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==4626== 
==4626== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4626== 
==4626== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4626== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Maybe it's because my program is using forks, pipes and exec calls. The goal of the program (pipex) is to do this :

`./pipex infile cmd1 cmd2 outfile` must be equivalent to bash `< infile cmd1 | cmd 2 > outfile`

Any hints on why this is happening and on how I can check errors and leaks ?

Comment: See the manual page for `--trace-children` and several other options that will be helpful.

Comment: You could also do something like `./pipex infile "valgrind cmd1" cmd2 outfile`. If your command line parsing doesn't handle double quotes/spaces that could be `./pipex infile cmd1.sh cmd2 outfile` where cmd1.sh contains `valgrind cmd1`.